# Proof of the Schwarz Lemma (simplified Cauchy/Clairaut Theorem)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, alternative-proof

My lecture notes states the following lemma (sometimes called [Cauchy's Theorem or Clairaut's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Schwarz.27s_theorem)) without proof:

> **Lemma.** (Schwarz) Assume that $v_\xi$, $v_\eta$, and $v_{\xi\eta}$ exist and are continuous. Then $v_{\eta\xi}$ exists and $v_{\eta\xi}=v_{\xi\eta}$.

The context is the wave equation in one dimension $u_{tt} = c^2u_{xx}$, where we had considered the characteristic coordinates
\begin{align}\xi &:= x+ct\\ \eta &:= x-ct \end{align}
(without loss of generality, we take $c>0$), and we had written the solution in new coordinates to be $u(x,t) = v(\xi, \eta)$.

I know that we can prove the more general theorem, but what is a proof just for this easy lemma?

Comment: use the definition of the derivative : as $t \to t_0$,   $\ \ f(t) = f(t_0) + (t-t_0)\frac{\partial }{\partial t} f(t_0) + o(|t-t_0|)$ and expand everything

Comment: at the end you get $v(\xi,\eta) - v(\xi_0,\eta_0) = (\xi-\xi_0) \partial_\xi(\xi_0,\eta_0) + (\eta-\eta_0) \partial_\eta(\xi,\eta_0) + o(|\xi-\xi_0|) + o(|\eta-\eta_0|) $ 

$ = (\xi-\xi_0) \partial_\xi(\xi_0,\eta_0) + (\eta-\eta_0) \partial_\eta(\xi_0,\eta_0) + (\eta-\eta_0)(\xi-\xi_0) \partial_\eta\partial_\xi(\xi_0,\eta_0)  + o(|\xi-\xi_0|) + o(|\eta-\eta_0|)+o(|\xi-\xi_0||\eta-\eta_0|)$

which is the definition of $\partial_\xi\partial_\eta(\xi_0,\eta_0)$

Comment: Mind turning this into an actual answer? I've been unable to find a proof anywhere so would really like this as a resource to refer back to.